# Getting DateTime in a format with spaces between them not slashes if possible

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I am trying to get date in this format

> "yyyy MM dd"

with spaces between them not slashes, but its not working

```
   using (SqlDataReader r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader())
    {
          if (r.Read())
          {
              DateTime Date 
= Convert.ToDateTime((r["Date"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

**I can't make any change to SQL Stored Procedure at all**

**EDIT**

Sorry it was giving me this for above **"25 10 2012 10:00:00:00 AM"** or something so I don;t think I was doing it properly, I only want date like this "yyyy MM dd"

Comment: Are you looking to display the date in that format or parse a date in that format?

Comment: What do you mean `or something`?!?  Is that the output you get or not!?

Comment: @Dems not sure about zeros if I will try to debug it again, it will actually gonna take me ages to b hoenst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about changing `\` into space?

```
.ToString("yyyy MM dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

From date to string

```
var str= date.ToString("yyyy MM dd")
```

and for string to date

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(string, "yyyy MM dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Marc's answer, it seems like you may be a bit confused about how the `DateTime` object vs. a `string` representation of the date actually work. The `DateTime` is just an offset from the starting point.

This line in your code first takes the value from the Date column in your SQL reader, then converts it to a string with the `"yyyy/MM/DD"` format, then finally turns that string into a `DateTime` object.

`= Convert.ToDateTime((r["Date"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));`

So as you can see, you're ending up with a `DateTime` object, not the display `string` you want. If you actually want this code to return just a formatted `string` , this is what your final line should look like:

**EDIT**

`= r.GetDateTime(r.GetOrdinal("Date")).ToString("yyyy MM dd");`

Comment: exception : Error 2 No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Comment: Sorry, there was a much better way of handling that. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

So you want this format: "yyyy MM dd" but you use this "yyyy/MM/dd".

Instead:

```
String dateString = r.GetDateTime(r.GetOrdinal("Date")).ToString("yyyy MM dd");
```

look: http://ideone.com/XecnUP

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` *does not have a format*. It is just the "how long since {epoch}", give-or-take some offset/timezone information. If the value in the source *is* a datetime, then all you need is:

```
DateTime date = (DateTime)r["Date"];
```

Then you might format that later at the UI. But to repeat: a `DateTime` *does not have a format*.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how this answer is anyway related to the OP's question. Granted I might be a noob, but a simple DateTime.ParseExact is what he was asking for.

Comment: @tranceporter since the OP accepted an answer related to `ToString()`, which is the **exact opposite** of `ParseExact`: I don't agree

Comment: @tranceporter: No, the OP is parsing a date (or an object with a format as a date) to a string and then converting it back to a datetime object. A DateTime, as Marc explained, does not have a format, but a format can be used (later in the UI) when needed by using the ToString or string.Format methods.

Comment: Not sure that was what OP wanted, but I will go with your assumption. Then again, he was trying to convert the ToString() to DateTime (Convert.ToDateTime((r["Date"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));), so ParseExact is not completely irrelevant!